# Ajax fetch data in PHP file for Highcharts

Tags: php, ajax, highcharts

I have `chart.php` and `chart-data.php`. In chart-data.php I have the following:

```
header("Content-type: text/json");

$categories = "categories: ['May 2017','June 2017','July 2017','August 2017','September 2017']";
$series = "[{
    name: 'Leads',
    data: [524, 419, 502, 598, 873,
    color: '#1a2b5f'
    }, 
    {
    name: 'Purchases',
    data: [37, 18, 32, 36, 44],
    color: '#00afef'    
}],";
$data = array($categories,$series);
echo json_encode($data);
```

And then in chart.php I have:

```
$.ajax({
    url     : "chart-data.php",
    type    : 'post',
    dataType: "json",
    success : function(data){
        options.xAxis.categories = data[0];
        var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);          
    }
});
```

Trying to add the dates as categories for the xAxis, however the dates aren't coming applying. When I use `alert(data)` I'm getting:

> categories: [             'May 2017','June 2017','July 2017','August
>   2017','September 2017'        ],[{name: 'Leads',          data: [524, 419, 502,
>   598, 873,             color: '#1a2b5f'
>             }, {            name: 'Purchases',          data: [37, 18, 32, 36, 44],             color: '#00afef'            }],

Could anyone perhaps point me in the right direction as at the moment I'm not having much luck with any of the changes I'm making!

Comment: I think their all goes in the same array, the categories as the first element but with structure like: [{
"name": "Date",
"data": ['May 2017','June 2017','July 2017','August 2017','September 2017']
}, {
"name": "Leads",
"data": [524, 419, 502, 598, 873],
"color" : '#00afef'
}, {...}]

Comment: Try changing `options.xAxis.categories = data[0]` to  `options.xAxis.categories = data[0].categories`.